# STM32F103RBT6. Проблема чтения поля структуры из флэша после его записи туда

Tags: c, stm32, embedded

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с непонятной мне в IAR`e вещью (пишу прошивку для STM32F103RBT6). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить.

Есть объявление структуры:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t f_Z_min_coord[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_max_coord[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_diff;
  uint32_t f_Z_discrete[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_mem_coord[MAX_CH_NUM]; 
  uint32_t f_Z_fz_height[MAX_CH_NUM];
} BridgeConfigStruct;
```

Есть её инициализация и размещение во флэше:

```
#pragma section = "FLASH"
#pragma location = "FLASH"
__root const BridgeConfigStruct BridgeConfigData_Default = 
{ 
  {0*Z_temp_discr, 0*Z_temp_discr},       //f_Z_min_coord
  {2000*Z_temp_discr, 2000*Z_temp_discr}, //f_Z_max_coord
  50,                                     //f_Z_diff
  {Z_temp_discr, Z_temp_discr},           //f_Z_discrete
  {1914, 1914},                           //f_Z_mem_coord
  {20*Z_temp_discr, 20*Z_temp_discr}      //Z_fz_height
};
```

Функции чтения-записи для флэша:

```
uint32_t  ReadPage(uint32_t flashAdr, uint16_t *buffer)
{
  uint32_t  i;
  if(!(flashAdr & (FLASH_PAGE_SIZE-1) )) 
  {
    for(i=0; i<FLASH_PAGE_SIZE/2; i++) 
    {
      buffer[i] = *(__IO uint16_t *)flashAdr;
      flashAdr += 2;
    }
  } 
  else return FALSE;
  return TRUE;
}

uint32_t WriteFlashPage(uint32_t flashStartAdr, uint8_t *dataPage)
{ 
uint32_t temp = TRUE;
uint16_t data;
uint32_t address, i;
__disable_interrupt();
FLASH_Unlock();

/* Clear All pending flags */
FLASH_ClearFlag( FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_PGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR);  
if(FLASH_ErasePage(flashStartAdr) == FLASH_COMPLETE) 
{
  address = flashStartAdr;
  for(i = 0; i < (FLASH_PAGE_SIZE/2); i++) 
  {    
    data = *dataPage++;
    data |= (((uint16_t)(*dataPage++)) << 8);
    temp = FLASH_ProgramHalfWord(address, data);
    address += 2;
    if(temp != FLASH_COMPLETE) 
    {
      temp = FALSE; 
      break;
    }
  }
  if(temp == FLASH_COMPLETE) temp = TRUE;
} 
else temp = FALSE;
FLASH_Lock();
__enable_interrupt();
return temp;
}

uint32_t  WriteFlash(uint32_t const *addr, uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
  uint32_t i, page_addr, index, result = TRUE;
  page_addr = ((uint32_t) addr)&0xFFFFFC00;
  if(ReadPage(page_addr, &flashPage.halfword[0]) == TRUE){
    index = (uint32_t) addr;
    index &= 0x000003FF;
    for(i=0; i< size; i++) 
    { flashPage.byte[index++] = *data++; }
    result = WriteFlashPage(page_addr, &flashPage.byte[0]);
  } 
  else result = FALSE;

  return result;
}
```

Использование поля структуры:

```
if(WriteFlash(&BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0], uint8_t*)&ZL_passed_height, 4) != TRUE)
{
  goto ErrorWriteFlashWrite;
   }
    else
     {
       volatile uint32_t *ptrZL_mem = (uint32_t*)0x08001028; //вариант №1

       volatile uint32_t ZL_mem_coord = *(ptrZL_mem);

       volatile uint32_t *ptrZL_mem = (volatile uint32_t *)&BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0]); //вариант №2

       volatile uint32_t ZL_mem_coord = *(ptrZL_mem);
}
```

Адрес BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0] в памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки оптимизации в проекте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, проблема - при данных настройках оптимизации при чтении BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0] после записи туда нового значения ZL_passed_height получаю:

- в варианте №1 ZL_mem_coord = ZL_passed_height (т.е. если напрямую читаю с того адреса, где размещен BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0] и куда прошла запись нового для него значения ZL_passed_height, то в ZL_mem_coord считывается записанное значение, равное ZL_passed_height)
- в варианте №2 ZL_mem_coord = BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0] (т.е. вместо нового записанного значения ZL_passed_height считывается значение BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0], задаваемое при её (структуры) инициализации, в данном случае это 1914)

Если же уровень оптимизации = None, то оба варианта ведут себя корректно.

При считывании прошивки из контроллера (при помощи J-Flash'a, например), по данному адресу (0x08001028) размещено новое записанное значение, равное ZL_passed_height (т.е. запись проходит корректно при обоих уровнях оптимизации).

Как порекомендуете исправить данную ситуацию (в интернетах ничего похожего пока не попалось)??

UPD: Продолжаю разбираться.
Записываю значение 2871(0xB37) через ZL_passed_height по адресу &BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0], т.е.

```
          if(WriteFlash(&BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0], (uint8_t*)&ZL_passed_height, 4) != TRUE)
          {
            goto ErrorWriteFlashWrite;
          }
          else
          {...}
```

Смотрю в IAR в отладке этот адрес памяти (0х08001028). Вижу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е вижу там значение инициализации 1914 (0x77A), а не записанное значение 2871 (0xB37).

Ок, выключаю отладку, смотрю этот же адрес через SEGGER J-Flash (Target -> ReadBack ->Entire Chip). Вижу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. что записал (2871), то и вижу (0хВ37).

Но при этом не могу получить (считать) корректно это значение при выполнении программы.

Чудеса ...

UPD2: В общем, разобрался чего там происходило - после рестарта контроллера восстанавливал из флэша неправильно.

Теперь связанный с чтением/записью структуры из/в флэша код выглядит так:

```
//***** main.h *****
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t f_Z_min_coord[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_max_coord[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_diff;
  uint32_t f_Z_discrete[MAX_CH_NUM];
  uint32_t f_Z_mem_coord[MAX_CH_NUM]; 
  uint32_t f_Z_fz_height[MAX_CH_NUM];
} BridgeConfigStruct;
```

---

```
//***** main.c *****
...
#pragma section = "FLASH"
#pragma location = "FLASH"
__root const BridgeConfigStruct BridgeConfigData_Default = 
{  
  {0*Z_temp_discr, 0*Z_temp_discr},       //f_Z_min_coord
  {2000*Z_temp_discr, 2000*Z_temp_discr}, //f_Z_max_coord
   50*Z_temp_discr,                       //f_Z_diff
  {Z_temp_discr, Z_temp_discr},           //f_Z_discrete
  {1914, 1914},                           //f_Z_mem_coord
  {20*Z_temp_discr, 20*Z_temp_discr}      //Z_fz_height
};

const BridgeConfigStruct *ptrBridgeConfData;
void Init_data(void);

#define Z_temp_discr 1914

volatile uint32_t ZL_discrete = Z_temp_discr;
volatile uint32_t ZR_discrete = Z_temp_discr;


volatile uint32_t ZL_minCoord;
volatile uint32_t ZR_minCoord;

volatile uint32_t ZL_maxCoord;
volatile uint32_t ZR_maxCoord;

volatile uint32_t Z_diff;

volatile uint32_t ZL_memCoord;
volatile uint32_t ZR_memCoord;

volatile uint32_t ZL_passedHeight = 0;
volatile uint32_t ZR_passedHeight = 0;

volatile uint32_t ZL_fz_height;
volatile uint32_t ZR_fz_height;

...

void Init_data(void)
{
  //ptrBridgeConfData = &BridgeConfigData_Default; //Вариант А

  ptrBridgeConfData = &BridgeConfigData_Default; //Вариант Б

  ZL_discrete = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_discrete[0];
  ZR_discrete = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_discrete[1];

  ZL_minCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_max_coord[0];
  ZR_minCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_min_coord[1];

  ZL_maxCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_max_coord[0];
  ZR_maxCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_max_coord[1];

  ZL_memCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_mem_coord[0];
  ZR_memCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_mem_coord[1];

  ZL_passedHeight = ZL_memCoord;
  ZR_passedHeight = ZR_memCoord;

  ZL_fz_height = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_fz_height[0];
  ZR_fz_height = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_fz_height[1];  
}

...

__task void main(void)
{ 
  ptrBridgeConfData = &BridgeConfigData_Default; //Вариант А

  //ptrBridgeConfData = &BridgeConfigData_Default; //Вариант Б

Init_data();

...

while(1)
{
...
 if(WriteFlash(&BridgeConfigData_Default.f_Z_mem_coord[0], (uint8_t*)&ZL_passedHeight, 4) != TRUE)
{
  goto ErrorWriteFlashWrite;
  }
   else
    {                                                                  
      ZL_memCoord = ptrBridgeConfData->f_Z_mem_coord[0];
      }
...    
  }
...
}
```

Но теперь другая интересная вещь - Вариант А записывает и считывает поля структуры после рестарта контроллера из его памяти  корректно, Вариант Б читает после рестарта поля структуры некорректно - снова вижу в переменных, заполняемых в Init_data(), значения из BridgeConfigData_Default. Хочу использовать Вариант Б как более логичный, но что-то он не работает как надо...

Что может быть причиной этого?

Comment: Может pragma pack

Comment: Спасибо, но, к сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Тип флеш-памяти какой? Она вообще поддерживает произвольный не выровненный доступ?

Comment: Да тупо запись/чтение флэша самого контроллера, без внешней памяти. Похоже, что при наличии оптимизации подставляется первоначальное значение поля при инициализации структуры вместо чтения нового записанного значения по его (поля) адресу. Попробую, кстати, другие поля структуры записать/считать - посмотрим, что из этого выйдет. Есть, конечно, вариант запихнуть кусок чтения в отдельную функцию и через #pragma запретить её оптимизировать, но это костыль. Хочу понять как сделать правильно всё-таки

Comment: А вообще запись произвольного массива байт у вас получается? То есть без привязки к вашей структуре.

Comment: Магия оптимизатора...
Покажите дизассемблер чтения 1 и 2. Подозреваю, что IAR наплевал на volatile и подсовывает значения из структуры без реального чтения.

Comment: Уже переписал эти куски иначе в поисках решения, но пока не решил. В понедельник выложу дизассемблер.

Comment: В общем, прогресс есть, но непонятки остаются (см. UPD2 в тексте вопроса)